# Python / How to delete specific rows in testing data with indices after / train / test / split

Tags: python, scikit-learn, delete-row, indices, train-test-split

I want to delete in X_test and in y_test every row where MFD is bigger one. The problem is, that i always get the random mixed indices from Train / Test / Split. If i try to drop it i get the following Error Message:

IndexError: index 3779 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 3488

I cant use the old indices to drop it, but how can i get the new ones where MFD > 1

```
  X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, 
                                                test_size=test_size, 
                                                random_state=random_state, 
                                                stratify=y)



mfd_drop_rows = []
i_nr = 0
for i in X_test.MFD:
   if (i > 1): 
      mfd_drop_rows.append(X_test.index[i_nr])
   i_nr += 1


X_test_new = X_test.drop(X_test.index[mfd_drop_rows]) 
y_test_new = Y_test.drop(Y_test.index[mfd_drop_rows])
```

Thanks for your help ( =

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what MFD is but assuming that `X_test.MFD` gives you an array of numbers you could use a mask to drop rows. A simple example of how to use a mask can be seen here:

```
x = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]
mfd = [0.6, 1.3]
mask = x > 1
x_new = x[mask,:]
```

This would give:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5
     6,7,8,9,10]
mask = [False, True]
x_new = [6,7,8,9,10]
```

Answer (score 0):

I ve solved it im sry, i just use my i_nr iteration and have the new indice.

Thanks to everyone who read it

```
mfd_drop_rows = []
i_nr = 0
for i in X_test.MFD:
 if (i > 1): 
    mfd_drop_rows.append(i_nr)
 i_nr += 1


 X_test_new = X_test.drop(X_test.index[mfd_drop_rows]) 
 y_test_new = Y_test.drop(Y_test.index[mfd_drop_rows])
```